# How can I remove a timestamp and special characters

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

**Batch File remove timestamp and special characters**

Using batch file command :

```
ren *_*.txt *_.txt
```

Result:

`TESTXXX_201708291703 ----> TESTXXX_`

**I want also to remove the underscore (_) character**

ie. `TESTXXX_201708291703 ----> TESTXXX`

Comment: Batch files or PowerShell: please pick *one*.

Comment: Batch file please

Comment: Environment variable substitution: `SET "VAR=%VAR:_=%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmdline

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %A in ('dir /B *_*.txt') Do @Echo Ren "%A_%B" "%A%~xB"
```

---

```
Ren "TESTXXX_201708291703.txt" "TESTXXX.txt"
```

I presumed you forgot the extension.
If the ouput looks OK, remove the echo.

In a batch file double the percent signs:

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%A in (
    'dir /B *_*.txt'
) Do Ren "%%A_%%B" "%%A%%~xB"
```

Comment: Thanks thats great :)